# comments between form fields in ext.js 2.3

Tags: forms, extjs, comments

I am new to ext.js and this may seem easy to some of you but not to me.
I have a form that is build with ext.js version 2.3. I am trying to place comments between the form fields. I mean the following:

- inputLabel1:  text form input
- commentLabel: some text
- inputLabel2:  text form field

I am having difficulty with the second line above. I don't need it to be an input field - just a label and some text next to it, which are aligned with the form labels and input fields on the rest of the rows.

Input fields are defined as follows:

```
var formParts =
  this.formParts = [];

  var receiptAmount = new Ext.Form.NumberField( {   
    id: 'receiptAmount',  
    name: 'receiptAmount',  
    cls:'inputNoRightBorder ',  
    fieldLabel: messages.amount,  
    allowNegative: true,  
    hideLabel: false,  
    decimalSeparator: messages.decimalSeparator,  
    decimalPrecision: 2,  
    groupingSeparator: messages.groupingSeparator,  
    value: 0,  
    labelSeparator:  messages.asteriskLineBreaker  
} );
```

Then they are placed in containers:

```
var grossAmount =   {
      border: false,
      layout: 'column',
      labelWidth: 190,
      cls: 'labelStyle',
      border: true,
      baseCls: 'ourPanel',
      items: [
        {
          id: 'receiptAmountContainer',
          border: false,
          layout: 'form',
          items: [receiptAmount]
        },
        {
          id: 'receiptCurrencyContainer',
          border: false,
          layout: 'form',
          items: [receiptCurrency]
        }
      ]
    };
```

The latter are placed in field sets:

```
var receiptFinancialData = {
      id: "receiptFinancialData",
      border: false,
      layout: 'column',
      labelWidth: 120,
      cls: 'column-style',//'#background-color: #DFE8F6',
      border: true,
      baseCls: 'ourPanel',
      height: 50,
      title: messages.taxRate + ':',
      header: false,
      items: [
        receiptExchangeRateMirror,
        receiptExchangeAmountMirror,
        {
          border: false,
          layout: 'form',
          items: [grossAmount]
        },
        {
          border: false,
          layout: 'form',
          cls: 'labelStyle',
          items: [taxRate]
        }
      ]
    };
```

And again:

```
  var singleLineItemContainer = new Ext.form.FieldSet( {
      id: 'singleLineItemContainer',
      name: 'singleLineItemContainer',
      cls: 'singleLineItemContainer',
      isActive: true,
      hideLabel: true,
      height: 'auto',
      items: [
        referenceCurrency,
        receiptType,
        entertainmentType,
        receiptFinancialData
      ]
    } );
```

And again:

```
var lineItemsContainer = new Ext.form.FieldSet( {
  id: 'lineItemsContainer',
  name: 'lineItemsContainer',
  header: false,
  border: false,
  height: 'auto',
  anchor: '100%',
  items: [
    toggleSingleMultyContainer,
    singleLineItemContainer,
    multipleLineItemsContainer,
    currencyAndExchangeSet
  ]
} );
```

And again:

```
var generalData = new Ext.form.FieldSet( {
  id: 'generalReceiptData',
  name: 'generalReceiptData',
  header: false,
  border: false,
  height: 'auto',
  anchor: '100%',
  items: [
    receiptClass,
    {
      id: 'generalDataReceiptCountryAndDate',
      border: false,
      layout: 'column',
      labelWidth: 120,
      cls: 'column-style',//'#background-color: #DFE8F6',
      border: true,
      baseCls: 'ourPanel',
      height: 50,
      header: false,
      items: [
        {
          id: 'generalDataReceiptDate',
          border: false,
          layout: 'form',
          cls: 'dateField',
          items: [receiptDate]
        },
        {
          id: 'generalDataReceiptCountry',
          border: false,
          layout: 'form',
          items: [receiptCountry]
        }
      ]
    },
    receiptDateString,
    receiptDescription,
    isCompanyPaid,
    lineItemsContainer
  ]
} );
```

The code above is placed in

```
Ext.extend( receiptForm, Ext.form.FormPanel,{
  initComponent: function(){
    above code
  }
}
```

Comment: could you share your code?

Comment: Well, ExtJS 2.3 is a bit old. Not sure whether a [`displayField`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Display) already existed back then. That field would be your solution. Or you can have a [`fieldcontainer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer) and fill the `html` property with your text.

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways to do this I'm sure. Here's a quick way to sorta hack it with css and readOnly fields

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18pa)

```
items: [{
    fieldLabel: 'inputLabel1',
}, {
    fieldLabel: 'commentLabel',
    readOnly:true,
    style:'background: transparent;border: none;',
    value:'some text',
}, {
    fieldLabel: 'inputLabel2',
}],
```

[image]

[This page](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-2.3.0/examples/samples.html) has some nice ext 2.3 examples, but why not learn with a newer version?

Comment: A lot of legacy code at the company I work for. At some point we will rewrite it all with a newer version or different technology